# Two Way Data Binding - Angular 2

Tags: angular

Im trying to make two way data binding with ngModel and it not working.
FormsModule is included.
 here the code:

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

test.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  person = {
    name: 'David',
    age: '17'
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

test.component.html:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.name" />
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.age" />
</form>

{{person.name}}<br />
{{person.age}}
```

Why it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in your console? You must add the name to your inputs as kemsky suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `name` attribute to inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to add

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

he understands he is no part of the form.