# Selected option in angular

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular8, html-select, angular-ngmodel

How i selected option in angular? I would select the item in my option list, how do I do? Thank you all.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select ngModel="skillSelezionate" multiple>
        <option *ngFor="let skill of listaSkill" [ngValue]="skill" ng-selected="skill.sigla === 'jee'" >
            {{skill.sigla}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{skill.descrizione}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: it's `[(ngModel)]="skillSelezionate"`, see the docs:https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control, and for forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Way Data Binding - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785027/two-way-data-binding-angular-2)

Comment: [Here's how you can achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000950/angular-4-setting-selected-option-in-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

You need the two way data binding on your `<select>` via `[(ngModel)]=" ... "`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="skillSelezionate" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let skill of listaSkill" [ngValue]="skill" ng-selected="skill.sigla === 'jee'" >
        {{skill.sigla}} - {{skill.descrizione}}
    </option>
</select>
```

You can learn more about template syntax here: [Template Syntax - Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)